# Writing rules in routes.php for Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I need a help for routes.php

I have 2 types of URLs like -
https://www.seekmi.com/service/jakarta/digital-marketing
and
https://www.seekmi.com/en/service/jakarta/digital-marketing

and for those i wrote 2 rules in routes.php with same controller as -

```
$route['en/service/(:any)/(:any)'] = "findservice/search/$1/$2";
$route['service/(:any)/(:any)'] = "findservice/search/$1/$2";
```

but only first URL works, not second one.
Can any one of you please help me resolve this issue ?

Comment: Your code looks okay. Check your .htaccess file. May be it creates some issue for you.

Comment: What does it mean that second doesn't work? 404? or points to wrong controller?

Comment: if `service/(:any)/(:any)` is same than i don't think you need to define two times the route setup.

Comment: @matiit, i thing it consider 'en' as controller which doesn't exists. And this is because of the rule is not getting apply for url like rule 1.

Comment: @Yash I need that the page should get access by both urls. 'en/' is just added for language translation for SEO purpose.

Comment: You can try `$route['(:any)/service/(:any)/(:any)'] = "findservice/search/$2/$3/$1";`

Comment: i can't take 'en' as '(:any)', or user can place any string instead of 'en' in url

Comment: Write this rule to remove en from URL: -RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]

Comment: try `$route['en/service/(:any)/(:any)'] = "findservice/search/$2/$3";`

Comment: @RaviHirani, i don't want to remove 'en' from URL. It needs to be there. And both URLs should give same result.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, Hi, it didn't worked.

Comment: @GaneshGadge: Okay.  Just remove your htaccess file and check without it. Because your codeigniter code looks okay.

Comment: What about just `$route['^(en)/service/([^/]+)$'] = "findservice/search/$2";`and  `$route['service/(:any)']         = "findservice/search/$1";` ??

Comment: @RaviHirani, if the htaccess removed then codeigniter will not work.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Actually my routes.php have other rules too, which will not work because of your suggestion. Let me give examples -

$route['en/service/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "findservice/professional_details/$1/$2/$3/$4";

$route['service/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "findservice/professional_details/$1/$2/$3/$4";

$route['en/service/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "findservice/index/$1/$2/$3";

$route['service/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "findservice/index/$1/$2/$3";

$route['en/service/(:any)/(:any)'] = "findservice/search/$1/$2";

Comment: Are u using any third party libraries like i18n ??

Comment: I have some 3rd party libraries like, carabiner, re-captcha, HybridAuth etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$route['service/(:any)/(:any)'] = "findservice/search/$1/$2";
$route['en/service/(:any)/(:any)'] = "findservice/search/$1/$2";
```

Comment: $route['en/service/(:any)'] = "findservice/search/$1/$2"; $route['service/(:any)'] = "findservice/search/$1/$2";

Answer (score 0):

The links are okay but the main aspect of the route mapping is the Controller and function name you specified in the setting. If they do not exist you will get 404 error.

So you need to create a findservice Controller and a method search in the controller to accept two parameters.

```
//save as findservice.php in application/controller/ folder

class Findservice extends CI_Controller{
   public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
   }
   public function search($param1,$param2){
      //use $param1 and $param2
   }
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In routes.php for CodeIgniter, follow these rules:

Define custom routes using the $route array.
Use URL patterns to map to specific controllers and methods.
Use placeholders {} to capture and pass parameters.
Set a default route for fallback behavior.
Remove index.php from URLs using .htaccess and config settings.
By adhering to these rules, you can effectively configure and manage URL routing in CodeIgniter.